# Problem when launching nav2_bringup with your own param file

Tags: nav2, turtlebot-bringup

I am encountering issues when attempting to pass my own parameter file while launching nav2_bringup. It appears that none of my configurations take effect. The command `ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py params_file:=my_nav2_params.yaml` is not working for me in Rolling.

I checked the launch.py script, and it seems that params_file is being taken into account. I’m unsure of what might be happening. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: "I believe the original post's title is self-explanatory"-- It's not. Please make sure your question is fully self-contained and doesn't require investigating through a removed question. Any specific information you have about specific errors or issues will be valuable, this question can't be answered otherwise.

Comment: You are right. I just edited it. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated nav2, and now it’s working. I’m not sure if it’s because of the update or if I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was different than yours - deleted question, issued PR.

Did you try with fully qualified path to your params file?

Are you sure your nav2_bringup package contains "nav2_bringup_launch.py"?
(I see "navigation_launch.py", "localization_launch.py", and "slam_launch.py" in the main branch)

Check: ls /opt/ros/rolling/share/nav2_bringup/launch/